# Excel: repeat the same values until a new one is found (dependent on another column)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large dataset of warehouses, items, days, snapshot hours, inventory quantity and binary instock rates (1 if there is inventory).

My issue is that not every hour has data. One hour might have either 5 in inventory and would be considered instock (value of 1), has no inventory and would have a value of 0, OR no data at all and would be considered out of stock. What I need is these values copied through the 24 hours, so I am assuming the other rows in that 24 hr day had the same inventory so that I have data I can add up. If there is absolutely no data for that day/warehouse/item combination for any of that day's hours, then I want to assume out of stock so 0. Is there an easy way to do this with a formula? I basically want to say for this warehouse, item, day combination, copy any numerical value within the 24 rows so I have an inventory qty and instock qty for all 24 rows. I don't really care if the inventory qty is accurate, but want the ability to see if the item was instock that day. Then it moves to the next warehouse/item/day combination in the row below.

Thanks for your help!

Table image below:

[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NMjp.png)

Comment: which column is written by user ? which column is depend on ?

Comment: the last two columns are using a vlookup to get the qty and instock data, but the other ones are pretty much written out by me

Comment: columns I through M are all values not formulas

Comment: use this way for the next Rows only (don't use for old data): use this formula in cells `J1000` (for example): `=IF(I1000<I999,"",J999)` and copy down, when you enter new data at hour 1 the new copies will be update

Answer (score 0):

> If there is absolutely no data for that day/warehouse/item combination for any of that day's hours, then I want to assume out of stock so 0.

```
=IF(OR(A1=0,A1=""),0,A1)
```

> copy any numerical value within the 24 rows so I have an inventory qty and instock qty for all 24 rows.

Assuming the original 'numerical value' doesn't contain formulas, and O26 is the formula location, `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",O26),TRUE),-24,0)` should do.